# how to return BOLD characters in python terminal

Tags: python-3.x, windows, colors

I'm trying to return a string as bold string.
I define a class called color

```
class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'
```

when I type  `print(color.BOLD + 'Hello World !' + color.END)` in the python console,it is print the **Hello World** in bold
But when I just type `color.BOLD + 'Hello World !' + color.END` in the terminal it is returning `'\x1b[1mHello World !\x1b[0m'`
I want to know how can I returning in bold characters?

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you type something that returns value in python console, it will automatically print its string representation. That means every unprintable escape characters will be printed as `\<something>`.
For example, newline has representation `\n`, carriage return `"\r"` etc. . If you pass escape character to `print` function, the escape character will be printed to console as it should be and terminal will treat it as signal for something (e.g. "go to new line" or "change color"), but its representation is actually character `"\"` followed by other characters.